# make table by adding count using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to add rows of count using the column name

Table Right Now:

```
count     name
3200      True
400       False
200       False
300       True
300       True
```

Desired Table:

```
count     name
3800      True
600       False
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby(['name'],as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: `df['name'].value_counts().to_frame()`